# Bind Property Of the ViewModel to CurrentCell

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I use a `WPF DataGrid`,

I want to `bind` the text of the `CurrentCell` (the edited cell)  with property that I have in  my`ViewModel`

**Is it possible to do this?**

**EDIT:**

I try this way:

```
 <DataGrid CurrentCell="{Binding MyProp}"...../>
```

I Get this error:

```
Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='<null>' BindingExpression:Path=MyProp; DataItem='MyViewModel' (HashCode=38365672); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='CustomCmdDg'); target property is 'CurrentCell' (type 'DataGridCellInfo')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it sucssed this way:

```
<DataGrid CurrentCell="{Binding MyProp, Mode=OneWayToSource}"...../>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem right.
But did you consider creating a DataTemplate with a label and bind its content property to the viewmodel property

Comment: Yes, The problem is that i want to bind property to the current edit cell

Comment: Did you tried it this way ? <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding myViewModelProperty}" 
/>

Comment: It bind to all datagridtextcolumn not to the current edit column